# PHP variables and query

Tags: php, postgresql, variables, identifier

I'm a bit confused with this: can I use PHP variables in a pg query?

```
$conn = pg_pconnect("...");
$a = 1
$b = array ("....")
$c = array ("....")
$d = array ("....")
$i = $a
$ct = "CREATE TABLE $a
(
$b[$i] bigint,
$c[$i] bigint,
$d[$i] bigint
)";

pg_query($conn, $ct);

$result = pg_query($conn, $ct);
if ($result) {$a = $a++}
```

Will this be able to create 10 tables if I loop this 10 times? Thanks!

Comment: What library are you using (`pg_query`, etc.)?

Comment: @EvanMulawski I'm using Postgres. Sorry for forgetting to mention that at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prepare your strings to to be **suitable identifiers for PostgreSQL** (mixed case? reserved words?) and safeguard against SQL injection at the same time, throw in a `pg_escape_identifier()`:

```
$ct = 'CREATE TABLE ' . pg_escape_identifier($a) . '(
' . pg_escape_identifier($b[$i]) . ' bigint,
' . pg_escape_identifier($c[$i]) . ' bigint,
' . pg_escape_identifier($d[$i]) . ' bigint
)';
```

Unless, of course, your identifiers are prepared already.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but you have to escape them:

```
$ct = "CREATE TABLE $a
(
{$b[$i]} bigint,
{$c[$i]} bigint,
{$d[$i]} bigint
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll work for $a but not for arrays. you should do something like:

```
$ct = "CREATE TABLE $a
(".
$b[$i]." bigint,".
$c[$i]." bigint,".
$d[$i]." bigint
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

**"can I use PHP variables in a query?"**

Yes, the query is just a string that's being passed to a function. You can do all of the string manipulation and concatenation that you could do with any other variable, before passing it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

> can I use PHP variables in a query?

Apparently you can't.
SQL query being executed by the SQL server which knows absolutely nothing of PHP.

However, you can add any number variables into a *PHP string*. Which can be sent to the SQL server. But of course there will be no variables in it, but just a plain text.

The syntax rules of PHP strings explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

For the debugging purposes you may use a great advantage of the PHP strings - the ability of printing them out.
Just `echo` your string out and see what you got and if it looks like correct SQL query. If not - correct the code.